# What does it take to be an `stl` algorithm compatible container?

Tags: c++, stl

1) For a given `stl` algorithm, how does one find out what custom container/iterator features one needs to implement in order to use said container?

2) What needs to be implemented to make container fully compatible with all `stl` algorithms?

Comment: @RSahu I disagree with your dupe target as the OP is not asking about how to implement an iterator but what iterator types does an algorithm need and how to support all algorithms with their container.

Comment: @NathanOliver, a container can be used in most, if not all, algorithms if it has the right iterators. Is that not true?

Comment: @RSahu And where is that in the dupe target?  Making a class iterable does not mean it will work with all algorithms.  The iterator type of the class does and the iterator type is not talked about.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I see your point.

Comment: None to both questions. STL algorithms now NOTHING about containers, so they make no requirements to the containers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11 standard it is stated in §25.1, in the footnotes:

> 3 All of the algorithms are separated from the particular implementations of data structures and are parameterized by iterator types. Because of this, **they can work with program-defined data structures, as long as these data structures have iterator types satisfying the assumptions on the algorithms.**

and then:

> 5 Throughout this Clause, the names of template parameters are used to express type requirements. If an algorithm’s template parameter is **InputIterator, InputIterator1, or InputIterator2, the actual template argument shall satisfy the requirements of an input iterator** (24.2.3). If an algorithm’s template parameter is **OutputIterator, OutputIterator1, or OutputIterator2, the actual template argument shall satisfy the requirements of an output iterator** (§24.2.4). If an algorithm’s template parameter is **ForwardIterator, ForwardIterator1, or ForwardIterator2, the actual template argument shall satisfy the requirements of a forward iterator** (§24.2.5). If an algorithm’s template parameter is **BidirectionalIterator, Bidirectional-Iterator1, or BidirectionalIterator2, the actual template argument shall satisfy the requirements of a bidirectional iterator** (§24.2.6). If an algorithm’s template parameter is **RandomAccessIterator, Random- AccessIterator1, or RandomAccessIterator2, the actual template argument shall satisfy the requirements of a random-access iterator** (§24.2.7).

So basically you need to provide your custom class a way to retrieve the usual iterators and these object must satisfy the requirement depending on which algorithm you want to support.

For example, let's take `std::any_of`, you can see it's declared as

```
template <class InputIterator, class Predicate> 
bool any_of(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred);
```

So you need to provide it an input iterator, then you can see at §24.2.3 the requirement for it and implement them:

- contextually convertible to bool (`a != b`)
- convertible to T (`*a`)
- dereferenceable (`a->m`)
- incrementable

Same story for each kind of iterator.

Answer (score 0):

STL algorithms use template types to describe the requirements of the function.  If you take [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) as an example

```
template<class RandomAccessIterator>
void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);
```

We can see that wee need to pass a random access compliant iterator.  So as long as the container you have has an iterator type of [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) or it supports all of the operations that RandomAccessIterator supports then you can use it with `std::sort`.

If we look at the iterator hierarchy on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)  We can see that in the current standard a [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) is a super-set of all other iterator types and supports all of the operations that the other iterators support.  So if a function calls for a InputIterator we can still give it an RandomAccessIterator.

So right now if your container has a RandomAccessIterator you can use it in any of the STL algorithms.